# Opencart error when selecting parent category

Tags: opencart, categories

With Opencart 2.0.1.0, I created categories. When i try to assign them parents, no category shows up.

Screenshots attached:

- http://snag.gy/30giO.jpg
- http://snag.gy/WmaCx.jpg
- http://snag.gy/nyFrF.jpg

Answer (score 1):

the autocomplete of choosing category only show the first five matches by default. Maybe you can type more character to get those categories?
Ref to: `\admin\controller\catalog\category.php` function: `autocomplete()`